# What is the difference between these three sentences?

Tags: meaning

> - What do you guess it means?
> - Do you guess what it means?
> - Can you guess what it means?

Question 1. Is there anything grammatically wrong the sentences above?
Question 2. What is the difference in meaning between the above sentences?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, these are all grammatically correct; but they imply different questions to me.

***-What do you guess it means?***

To me, this question is simply asking **what** a person thinks something means. I would expect an answer like "I think it means this."

***-Do you guess what it means?***

This way sounds more like asking **whether or not** they guess, rather than **what** they guess it means. This would imply a "yes" or "no" answer.

***-Can you guess what it means?***

And this question seems to be asking if the person is **able** to guess it, implying a more challenging question with a less-definite answer like "I think so" or "I'm not sure".